# How can I get the count of how many times a string is inside a long NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have the following long `NSString`:

```
    <span class='page-numbers current'>1</span>
    <a class='page-numbers' href='http://www.testurl1.com'>2</a>
    <a class='page-numbers' href='http://www.testurl2.com'>3</a>
    <a class='page-numbers' href='http://www.testurl3.com'>4</a>
```

I am trying to find out how many times the string `page-numbers` is in this `NSString`. Is there a simple method to do this?

Comment: As you are looking at HTML/XML you might consider NSXMLParser depending on what you need to scale to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the below code to get the count

```
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"page-numbers"];
int count = [array count]-1;
```

I think the above code will be useful to you..

Comment: It would be `[array count] - 1;` I think.

Comment: For example, the string `"a page-numbers b"` would be separated into "a" and "b".  Count would be 2.  But "page-numbers" only exists once.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with some JS scripts.

```
eg: documents getelementbyid
```

then , you can get the count.

ps: js script should run in a webview.

Answer (score 0):

use NSRegularExpression, is more efficient and clear.

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"page-numbers"
                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Comment: Regular expressions are rarely more efficient.